# Jenkins, xcodebuild -> JUnit-Tests with Appium?

Tags: junit, jenkins, xcodebuild, appium

i am using Jenkins CI to build my iOS-Project. For this task, I use a sh-script to build the binaries directly from a git-repo by running xcodebuild and thats working pretty well.
Currently I run JUnit-tests with appium from eclipse to test my app, but I would like to integrate them into Jenkins as well. I found some tutorials to integrate JUnit-tests into jenkins by using ant-scripts, but I dont use ant to build my project. 
how can I integrate my JUnit-tests into jenkins, without a ant-script? Or should I use a ant-script?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched now to [Gradle Build Automation](http://www.gradle.org/) which is much easier to handle and can be integrated into Jenkins as well by using [Jenkins Gradle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin). xCode-Projects can automatically be build from Gradle by using [Gradle xcode plugin](http://openbakery.org/gradle.php) and its easy to integrate JUnit or NGTests into a Gradle Scripts. In java test classes I am able to use [selenium driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) against [appium server](http://appium.io/) who's remote controlling iOS-Simulator.

Comment: could you post your build.gradle?  curious how you're using appium w/ gradle and Xcode...